# How to stop Cheat Engine and other memory modificators (JAVA application, Minecraft)

Tags: memory, java, memory-management, minecraft

I am looking for solution on how to prevent Cheat Engine and other memory modification programs. I am working for one Minecraft server, and we have problems with CE and memory modificators because javaw.exe process is obviusly not protected and they can easily write on memory and modify what they want before entering the server, then use modified values there... How to protect process from memory write ? What to do ? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Add more detail about your computer configuration and how can others run their programs on your server.

Comment: @harrymc If I am understanding correctly, others aren't modifying the server, they are modifying their clients which are connected to the server.

Comment: They modify their ram actually... I had idea of making my own minecraft launcher but and protect files but... :/

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do. It's their memory that they're modifying, not yours. If the game trusts values provided by clients, then it's a protocol design fault and - again - there's nothing you can do.